# Central Limit Theorem Variant

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Given an input of 4096-dimensional independent and identically distributed (iid) vectors, and an output obtained by performing weighted summation on these iid vectors using coefficients that are also iid, can it be proven that the resulting output conforms to a normal distribution?

Comment: I'm confused about what the question is asking. So we have $X_1,...,X_{4096}$ iid random variables, and the question is if there exists random coefficients $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{4096}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{4096} \alpha_i X_i$ is a normal distribution?

Comment: Sorry for confusion.I mean if $X_1, \ldots, X_{4096}$ are iid random variables,$\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_{4096}$ are another iid random variables,is $\sum_{i=1}^{4096} \alpha_i X_i$ will be a normal distribution?

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot be proven- in fact, it is false in general. For one, this is a problem of finite numbers of random variables, and the Central Limit Theorem deals with the behavior of random variables in the limits of sample sizes. Even for something as simple as taking an average of a set of iid random variables, where the CLT applies in the limit, the distribution of the mean will *not* be normal for any finite sample size unless the underlying distribution is itself normal.

If you're asking whether the CLT would apply to, say, the average of values generated from that process as the sample size grows without bound, the answer is still no in general. The CLT requires that the random variables have finite first and second moments. You would need to make the additional assumption that the product of the two distributions has finite first and second moments.

Comment: Thanks for your anser.If we assume $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_{N}$ are fixed weights sampled from another iid random variables and N tends to $\infty$.Can we prove $\sum_{i=1}^{N} \alpha_i X_i$ conforms to a normal distribution?

Comment: No. If either $\alpha$ or $X$ have nonzero mean, then the mean of that sum goes to infinity. If either have nonzero variance (which is the case for any random variable that isn't constant!) then the sum will have infinite variance. I'd suggest looking at some proofs that make use of the CLT and looking at the sequences of random variables that they consider- scaling the sequence is necessary. And $\alpha X$ must have finite mean and variance. You can determine that from properties of each and independence, but you must demonstrate it.

Comment: Thank you very much.I want to konw if $X$ and $\alpha$ both have limited mean and variance,can $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} \alpha_i X_i$ be proved to a normal distribution?